# Asus BIOS resets to default configuration when the PC is rather cold

Tags: bios, fan, cpu-cooler, asus

Since a few days (it's getting colder here) I have an annoying problem:

When I power on my PC, it starts for a few seconds, then powers off to reboot with a verbose message screen saying "CPU Fan error / Press F1".

At that time the CPU spins with something like 550RPM.
So I checked the settings: The lower speed warning was actually set to 600 RPM, so I adjusted it to 500RPM.

However the problem still occurs, and then all BIOS settings are reset to default so that  my PC won't boot anyway (it needs RAID mode, not AHCI mode).

Here is what I see a few moments after entering BIOS:

[image: ASUS Z87-C BIOS Version 2103]

What could I do to fix it?
I suspect that the CPU fan is spinning slowly because:

1. It's cold and it doesn't have to spin faster
2. The cold temperature is making the oil somewhat thicker, so the fan spins a bit slower than usual
3. The fan and its bearings are getting older and maybe some dust makes the fan spin a bit slower than usual

Before someone asks:
Of course the CPU fan speeds up once the CPU gets warmer.

Comment: Starting a computer that cold is bad for it.  Get a heating pad, and an open grill with vents to put on top, and the computer on top to warm it . Set it low and a timer to turn the pad on 3 hours before you need to start it.

Comment: Actually I'd like to contribute to energy saving and not warming up the atmosphere instead (rendering HD videos will anyway) ;-)

Comment: I appreciate that but you will likely contribute more by warming up the computer than by prematurely wearing it out

Comment: Also check the coin cell for timer, and possibly BIOS: as it gets colder, the voltage may drop. Try a new cell, if possible.

Comment: I see a temp of 71 degrees F in your picture.  HOW cold is cold?  What @John says *can be* true.  People don't agree on what the magic number is but generally anything under 50 deg F *can be* a problem depending on the hardware.  I myself have a computer in the garage that sometimes hits freezing (or below) and still had no problem with it.  I don't care about it or I might not do that.  Cold makes batteries weak.  Your CMOS battery might struggle in a cold room.

Comment: I also think that if the fan is too slow (cold, not turning well) that the CPU could get hotter than normal.

Comment: @John If the slow spinning fan would make the CPU heat up faster, then the fan will also spin up faster ;-)

Comment: The relationship is not linear.  A CPU will fry to death in mere seconds without a fan. A fan has mass and will take a while to heat up. My overall point is that a computer that is routinely too cold will wear out prematurely

Comment: @John You are mixing up several things: First the fan does not cool the CPU directly; instead the heatpipes of the cooler will take the heat from the CPU and the fan will take the heat from the cooler. Second it's not the heat of the fan that will make it spin faster, but the CPU's temperature sensor read by the motherboard, controlling the PWM fan in turn. Eventually the period when the computer is too cold is probably just a few minutes, and I think the *temperature change* is more a problem than the actual temperature.

Comment: In computers I have seen (all of them) the fan is attached to the CPU or on an air tube attached to the CPU. If a Fan is not working , the computer may not even start. So I merely note that a Fan not working fast enough leads to premature wear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I could resolve the issue, but it's interesting:

- Initially I had suspected that the "BIOS battery" might be weak, but as the date and time were still correct when entering the BIOS, I concluded that it was not the case.
- Furthermore I assumed that today's BIOSes store their configuration in flash memory (and no longer in battery-backed-up "NVRAM).

Amazingly even when I had lowered the minimum "CPU Fan Speed" step by step, I still got the "CPU Fan error, press F1 to enter Setup".
So why would it continue to complain, even when the sounds suggested that the CPU fan *does* work?

So I started to investigate by opening the case and taking a video of the power on sequence (I cannot include an video via imgur here, so I just show a still image from the video):

[image: Opened Desktop Case showing all fans spinning]

After a few days I had noticed that the date was still correct, but the time of day was several hours behind, so I took out the BIOS battery to measure it:
It had about 1.5V left (instead of 3.3V nominal), so I replaced it.

Still at the next power-on, I still got the "CPU Fan error", so I entered BIOS Setup again, and restored my default profile (fortunately Asus BIOS allows to save several sets of "tuning profiles").

*Then*, after another boot cycle the problem was gone!

## Conclusion

The actual problem was Asus BIOS loosing it's settings due to a weak BIOS battery.

That also means that the configuration data is *not* stored in flash memory, but in battery-backed-up "NVRAM" (which was actually volatile (not "NV") in that case).

So the "CPU Fan error" was because of the BIOS default settings being applied *silently* due to a weak battery causing loss or corruption of the previous settings.
The default minimum allowable CPU speed was 600 RPM, but my (deliberately chosen slow and silent CPU fan started with something like 580 RPM when the CPU was cold), so the BIOS triggered a fan failure.

Another example of poor BIOS code quality (running the latest BIOS available from Asus for that hardware).
Couldn't it say "*Configuration reset to default due to invalid NVRAM*" or simply "*Battery depleted, please replace it!*"

### Remark

Actually it could even get worse:
I know a case where a weak battery left garbage in NV RAM, and BIOS tried to work with that garbage, causing a completely unbootable computer; you could not even enter BIOS setup (you had to take out the battery for a very long time, then retry).
But honestly in that case there was a BIOS update available that at least detected the corrupted NVRAM and started with default settings then...

Answer (score 0):

> What could I do to fix it? I suspect that the CPU fan is spinning
> slowly because it's cold

What you have observed is correct. Further cold mechanical devices with cold oil will get damaged unless otherwise specifically designed (good auto engines for example).

If you wish a solution to prevent the computer being too cold, you must find a way to heat it before turning it on. This is what can you do to alleviate the situation.

(1) Move it to a warmer room if you can.

(2) Devise a heating pad with a ventilated grill to put on top and then the computer on top of that. Set the pad to a low temperature (less energy) and a timer to turn in on prior to using the computer.

Overall I suspect the longer the computer will last this way will outweigh the cost of the energy and even means less pollution from recycling prematurely worn equipment.

These seem to be the prime ways to warm the computer.